# contract successfully deployed but truffle says the opposite

Tags: deployment, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I deployed a contract with truffle on the mainnet and it's been successfully verified(here's the contract https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeb0a0f698d0e6a0081c6d95a4e03175d61582115f920fdf4acd7e77ba40136a5). So i payed for the gas and it should be deployed by now but whenever i try to use it in the truffle console(`let instance = await MyContract.deployed();` i get

```
Uncaught:
Error: MyContract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

Why is that? I payed for the deployment. What else truffle needs?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the JS code using the `MyContract.deployed()` function, as well as the config. Redact any sensitive data such as mnemonic phrase or private key.

Answer (score 0):

Truffle suite is very buggy . I myself have been having  issues with truffle from time  to time  . So i highly recommend for you to move to hardhat instead.